# Solve symbolic Sylvester-like equation in MATLAB or MAPLE

Tags: matrix-equations, matlab, maple, sylvester-equation

I'm looking for a way to solve a symbolic Sylvester-like equation in MATLAB or MAPLE (or any other available tool). In particular, I have the following equation,

$$AX+XA=B$$

where, $A$ has some parameters in it, e.g.,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a+1 & 2\\3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$B$ is known and I want to solve for $X$ as a function of $a$.

Comment: Matlab has now a "sylvester" function https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sylvester.html

Comment: Why not use vectorization?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, but the input arguments must be numeric arrays.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can you please describe more?

Comment: [Vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) converts the matrix equation into a system of $4$ linear equations in $4$ unknowns, which is easy to solve symbolically. In MATLAB, use `kron` for the Kronecker product and `reshape` for the vectorization and un-vectorization.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Got you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [write the Sylvester equation as a linear system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_the_solutions):
\begin{equation}
(I_2 \otimes A + A^T \otimes I_2) \mathrm{vec} X = \mathrm{vec} B
\end{equation}
which you can then solve for $\mathrm{vec}X$:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{vec}X 
& = (I_2 \otimes A + A^T \otimes I_2)^{-1} \mathrm{vec} B \\
& = \frac{\mathrm{adj} (I_2 \otimes A + A^T \otimes I_2)}{\mathrm{det} (I_2 \otimes A + A^T \otimes I_2)} \mathrm{vec} B
\end{align}
and finally reshape back to a 2 by 2 matrix.